# Writing to a script tag after page loads

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```html
<script>
  document.querySelector( 'html' ).innerHTML += 'hello';
</script>

<script>
  document.querySelector( 'script' ).innerHTML += 'alert( "world?" )';
</script>
```

The `alert()` function does not fire on page load. This is an overly simplified example but the desired result is to inject additional JavaScript code into a `script` tag after the page has loaded.

How can this code be altered so that the `alert` function properly fires in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

If you have jQuery, you can just use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getScript("http://jact.atdmt.com/jaction/JavaScriptTest");
});
```

In plain javascript, you can load a script dynamically at any time like this:

```
var tag = document.createElement("script");
tag.src = "http://jact.atdmt.com/jaction/JavaScriptTest";
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(tag);
```

Comment: Thanks. But is it possible to write to an existing script tag using only vanilla JS? I'm asking this question solely to know the capabilities and limits of JavaScript itself. Also why doesn't my specific example work?

Comment: That's not adding JavaScript to an existing script element, it's creating a new script element and adding it to the document.

Comment: The reason why your example does not work: you can find possible reasons here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element

Answer (score 0):

This won't work because the [HTML spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html#innerhtml0) doesn't allow for scripts inserted using `innerHTML` to be executed.

> script elements inserted using innerHTML do not execute when they are inserted.

What you can instead do is use the `document.createTextNode()` method to insert your script body.

```html
<script>
    document.querySelector( 'html' ).innerHTML += 'hello';
    const scriptTag = document.createElement("script");
    const scriptNode = document.createTextNode("alert('Hello World!');");
    scriptTag.appendChild(scriptNode);
    document.body.appendChild(scriptTag);
</script>
```